# Submit to SQL Server from AJAX JSON --> Web Method

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, ajax

I have been working through a solution to get data from a webpage submitted through AJAX to a WebMethod, and ultimately into a database. I am stuck as to what I do with the Web Method code block once the AJAX `Get` method completes.

Here is my AJAX

```
function UpdatePeople() {
    var PeopleToUpdate = [
            { "name": "John", "age": "17" },
            { "name": "Harry", "age": "19" },
            { "name": "Steve", "age": "23" }
        ];

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '_ajax_updatepeople.aspx/UpdateOnDemand',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({'PeopleToUpdate' : PeopleToUpdate }),
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Here is my Web Method and Public Class

```
[WebMethod]
public string UpdateOnDemand(List<People> PeopleToUpdate)
{
    // What do I do here ?????
}

public class People
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, in my Web Method I am stuck as to how I access this JSON data and do something with it. This is what I have tried and it does not work at all. Is there anything I can do to correct this or do I need to take another approach? The error that comes up (which may not be the only thing wrong here anyway) is that cannot convert from `Generic.List` to String (in the case of the dynamic content.... section)

```
[WebMethod]
public string UpdateOnDemand(List<People> PeopleToUpdate)
{
    dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<People>(PeopleToUpdate);

    foreach (var Item in content)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = null;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = null;

        try
        {
            myConnection = DBConnectConfig.openDBConnection();

            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Users (Name, Age) VALUES (@Name, @Age)");
            sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Item.name);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Age", Item.age);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        finally
        {
            DBConnectConfig.disposeDBObjects(myConnection, sqlCmd);
        }
    }

    return "People added to the database";
}
```

Am I remotely on the right track, or not at all?

Comment: For one, your JSON is already Deserialzed when it comes to the WebMethod and transformed to List<People>, so you don't need to do that. Which line were you getting the error on?

Comment: Thanks @KingOfArrows, sorted this error now as per the post below from Martin. It seems the errors from the console are gone, however nothing seems to be happening at all. My database is not updating so i'm wondering if something else is not right. I'm struggling to even get some sort of return to indicate what might be the issue.

Comment: If you have Sql Server Management Studio installed, you can open up Sql Profiler which you can see the sql commands that are run on the server. That way you can check what parameters are being passed in. Also Get rid of the @ symbol on the line sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Item.name);

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. A few things to mention

1) this line is not needed

```
dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<People>(PeopleToUpdate);
```

because ASP.NET already did the conversion from JSON string into the class `People` for you, the method `UpdateOnDemand(List<People> PeopleToUpdate)` already has the deserialized model.

2) you could loop through the collection of people

```
foreach (var person in PeopleToUpdate)
```

3) if your [domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) consists of multiple classes with relationships among them, 
 you might consider using an ORM such as Entity Framework for the data layer.

4) structure of solution could be modified, an exaple of projects structure

- MySolution.Data (data access)
- MySolution.Business (for business components, uses Data)
- MySolution.Web (uses Business)
- MySolution.Data.Test (xUnit/NUnit project for testing data access layer)

An example of a business component

```
public class PeopleService: IPeopleService
{
    public PeopleService(/* inject settings with connection string */)
    {
    }

    public void UpdatePeople(List<People> people)
    {
        var dal = new DALContext(.. connection string from settings);
        data.UpdatePeople(people);
    }
}
```

DAL component:

```
public class DALContext
{
    // this method can be unit tested:
    public void UpdatePeople(List<People> people)
    {
        .. code for database operations
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this has definitely gotten me through the part that was erroring and I believe there are no more errors. Only problem is that my database is failing to update, and i can't actually seem to put a break inside this Web Method to pause to make sure it's all processing as I would expect. I've even put a Response.Redirect as the first line within the web method to see at least if the Web Method is running, and it fails to even redirect. Anything else from looking at the code snippets you can see which could prevent this?

Comment: For solving isues with database operation, it might help to structure your solution, to put the logic of saving and loading from database into a separate project in your solution. Then it would be possible to create unit tests (xUnit) for classes in this new project. The answer shows an example.

Comment: One small thing, the method us called UpdateOnDemand, and it does inserts.

Comment: Thanks for your help Martin. I'll try and learn more about what you've described as the way i'm trying to update the database simply is not working. i can move this into a standard method and it works just fine, but when trying to get the same thing updated through an ajax call it's not working and i'm struggling to get any kind of response back to indicate why.